# Não entra no bloco ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Bom Dia!

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<?php
   $titulo = "Site";
?>
<html>
    <head>
      <title><?php echo $titulo; ?></title>
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="_imgs/favicon.ico">    
      <script type="text/javascript" src="_scripts/_js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="_css/estilo.css" />    
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="corpo">

      <div class="cabecalho">
          <h2 id="tituloCabecalho"> Bem Vindo ao Portal do Cliente <a href="index.php"><?php echo $titulo; ?></a> </h2>
      </div>

      <div id="formLogin" class="login">
        <form action="" method="post" >
         <label>Entrar</label> <br /> <br />
         <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="email" placeholder="E-mail" class="camposForm" required /> <br /> <br />
         <input type="password" name="senha" id="senha" class="senha" placeholder="Senha" class="camposForm" required /> <br /> <br />
         <input type="checkbox" name="lembrar" id="lembrar" class="lembrar" /> <label id="lembrarLabel">Lembrar-me</label>  <br /> <br />
         <div class="entrarRecuperar">         
           <div class="entrarDiv"><button id="entrar" class="btnEntrar">Entrar</button></div>
           <div class="recuperarDiv"><a href="recuperaSenha.php">Esqueceu sua senha?</a></div>
         </div>
         <div class="clear"></div>
         <div id="erroLogin"></div>
        </form>     
      </div><br>

      <div class="cadastro">Registro</div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>

<script>
    $('#entrar').click(function () {
        email = $('#email').val();
        senha = $('#senha').val();
        if (email=="") {
            alert("Preencha E-mail");
            return false;
        }
        if (senha=="") {
            alert("Preencha Senha");
            return false;
        }

        $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "_requeridos/sessaoLogin.php",
             data: {email: email, senha: senha},
             dataType: 'json'
            }).done(function(resposta){
              alert();
              if (resposta == "ERRO") {
                  $("#erroLogin").html("Erro de Login");              
              } else {
                  window.location="oi.html";
              }
        });

        return false;
    });
</script>
```

O js  `$.ajax({` acima não é capaz de encontrar os valores dos campos do formulário.

O que está errado nesse código?

Na verdade nem entrando no no Ajax está.

Comment: Nunca usei esse tipo de formatacao pro bloco Ajax, geralmente eu utilizaria um atributo `success` recebendo uma `function (data)` no proprio objeto ajax ( em baixo de datatype).. Testa isso e ve se funciona. E outra, o servidor esta recebendo e tratando a requisicao corretamente? Ja tentou utilizando um postman da vida?

Comment: Já tentou capturar o `fail` da requisição para verificar se a ela falhou?

Comment: Achei o erro: era que no php eu estava imprimindo direto sem usar a função json_encode. Obrigado

Comment: Alguerm sabe explicar o que retorna no .done? Se é a mesma coisa que está em sucess e faillure?

Comment: O `done` irá corresponder a utilizar o `success` com alguns pequenos detalhes de implementação diferentes. O servidor está a receber o pedido ou não ? Aparece algum erro no browser ? ou no servidor ?